# Real-time basic web analytics with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I need to develop an in-house *real-time* analytics solution (similar to GA or mixpanel for example) that collects:

- Information from the website itself ­­(URL)
- Information from the user’s browser ­­(lang, device, OS etc..)
- Information from the referring source etc..

.. and sends this data to the server with a single-pixel image request. Similar to how GA and other solutions work:

> Google Analytics works by the **inclusion of a block of JavaScript code**
>   on pages in your website. When users to your website view a page, this
>   JavaScript code references a **JavaScript file which then executes the
>   tracking operation** for Analytics. The tracking operation retrieves
>   data about the page request through various means and **sends this
>   information to the Analytics server via a list of parameters attached
>   to a single-pixel image request**.

I wonder if there's any open source project available that does this part which I could use as base to build further. There's `Piwik` but its too feature-packed and too heavy for my requirement.

Edited to add: I'm doing something specific with the data, otherwise I'd just use the existing solutions.

Comment: Have you checked out OWA? 
http://www.openwebanalytics.com/

Comment: Why don't you use the tracker from Piwik or OWA and then bypass the backend and pull the data from the db to do your stuff (I think they both run on MySql ? That would you would have a widely tested tracker and don't need to worry that any homegrown solution interferes with other scripts on your site.

Comment: There is also Snowplow (https://github.com/snowplow/) if you need a solution that scales, but that runs in the cloud - don't know if you want/need that.

Comment: `The Snowplow JavaScript Tracker is based on Anthon Pang's piwik.js, the JavaScript tracker for the open-source Piwik project` Interesting.

Comment: https://github.com/mnutt/hummingbird also seems interesting but the project doesn't seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: http://danml.com/js/blackbox.js captures a lot more data than google, but it's up to you to ship it somewhere. a JSON output of it should all fit in a queryString though.

Comment: @dandavis wow, can you please submit an answer with usage instructions if possible so i could award you the bounty! Thanks

Comment: all you need to send it to a server is something like `new Image().src="/rec.php?data="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(blackbox));` you can then use something like json_decode($_GET['data']); in php to get the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var img = new Image;
img.width = img.height = "1px";
var res = window.navigator;
var data = {};
var _plugins = {};
Array.prototype.slice.call(navigator.plugins).forEach(function(v, k) {
  _plugins[v.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/, "-")] = {
    "name": v.name,
    "description": v.description,
    "filename": v.filename
  }
});
delete res.plugins && delete res.mimeTypes;
data.url = window.location.href;
data.ref = document.referrer;
data.nav = res;
data._plugins = _plugins;
// set `img` `dataset` with `data` ,
// send `img` to server , decode `img` `dataset` at server
img.dataset.stats = JSON.stringify(data);
```

```js
var img = new Image;
img.width = img.height = "1px";
var res = window.navigator;
var data = {};
var _plugins = {};
Array.prototype.slice.call(navigator.plugins).forEach(function(v, k) {
  _plugins[v.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/, "-")] = {
    "name": v.name,
    "description": v.description,
    "filename": v.filename
  }
});
delete res.plugins && delete res.mimeTypes;
data.url = window.location.href;
data.ref = document.referrer;
data.nav = res;
data._plugins = _plugins;
img.dataset.stats = JSON.stringify(data);
document.write(
  img.dataset.stats       
);
```

Comment: Hm.. I'd prefer a widely tested solution that works cross-browser and is known to be stable.

Comment: @3zzy Yes, `element.dataset` may not be supported by all browsers, .e.g., ie<11 . Another option may be to utilize `$.post(url, data)` instead of `data` attached to an elements' `dataset` property. If requirement is to utilize an html element for `data` storage / transfer , could create `blob` of a `div` or `span` element having `data` as text/html; send element to server ? Though sending as plain text perhaps simplest to retrieve/process at server `$.post(url, JSON.stringify(data))` ?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 big solutions for open source analytics.

Piwik as you mentioned is a well documented and pretty mature solution. Drilling down the code, how Piwik makes things come around will give you some insights.

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) is the other big player on the game. A more simplified tool which will help you understand how basic tracking is made.

Depending on the data you want to track I would also suggest taking a look on this [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/real-time-web-analytics-with-node-js-and-socket-io/) which uses sockets in order to track real time data.

Least but not last you can also check what Crazy Egg does if you want to track down user's interactivity.